# Derivative: Finding the normal line

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have to find the normal line.

$$x^2-4x-5 ;(-2,7)$$

So, I have to find the equation of tangent line at $(x_1,y_1)$ which is,

$$2x_1-4$$

Now the equation at the (-2,7) is,

$$y-7=-8(x+2)$$
$$8x+y+9=0$$

Now, how do I find the normal line??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The normal line is: $$y - 7 = m(x+2), m = -\dfrac{1}{2x_1-4} = \dfrac{1}{8}\implies 8y-56 = x + 2 \implies x - 8y +58 = 0$$

Comment: The answer book says that it's $x-8y+56=0$ does the book have a typo perhaps??

Answer (score 1):

$$y=x^2-4x-5 \\\frac{dy}{dx}=\operatorname{slope}(x)=2x-4\\\text{ @ (-2, 7):}\\\frac{dy}{dx}\Big|_{x=-2,\;y=7}=-8=m\\\text{"normal" = perpendicular (}\perp\text{)}\\m_{\perp\xi}=-\frac1{m_\xi}\\\text{(slope of the line }\xi_\perp\text{, the line perpendicular to } \xi\text{ is the negative reciprocal of }\xi\text{'s slope)}\\\frac{dy_\perp}{dx}\Big|_{x=-2,\;y=7}=\frac18=m_\perp\\y_\perp=m_\perp x+b=\frac{x}8+b\\\text{If they meet at (-2,7):}\\7=\require{cancel}-\cancelto{\frac14}{\frac28}+b \\ \Rightarrow b=\frac{29}{4}$$

Comment: Why the near downvote?

Comment: Maybe because the requisite point is $(-2,7)$, not $(-2, 4)$?  Anyway, I wouldn't downvote for that.  What is a "near downvote", anyway?  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis My apologies, fixed. By "near downvote" I mean that someone downvoted me, but then took it away.

Comment: You received grace!  And no need to apologize! Thanks, Cheerio!

Answer (score 1):

I'll betcha that the easiest way to do is to use the well-known fact that any normal to a line of slope $m$ has slope $-m^{-1}$.  This follows from the identity

$(\tan \theta)(\tan(\theta + \dfrac{\pi}{2})) = -1, \tag{1}$

which itself may be seen from

$\tan(\theta + \dfrac{\pi}{2}) = \dfrac{\sin(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2})}{\cos(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2})} = \dfrac{-\cos \theta}{\sin \theta} = -(\tan \theta)^{-1}; \tag{2}$

(2) follows from the angle addition formulas for $\sin$ and $\cos$, i.e. $\sin (\alpha + \beta) = (\sin \alpha)(\cos \beta) + (\sin \beta)(\cos \alpha)$ and so forth.  (Follows, that is, when $\theta \ne 0$.  For $\theta = 0$, take limits as $\theta \to 0$ or just create an exceptional case.)  In any event, (2) implies my previous assertion on slopes of perpendicular lines.  In the present case, the slope of the tangent is $-8$, so the slope of the normal is $1/8$.  Thus the equation of the normal line through $(-2,7)$ is

$y - 7 = \dfrac{1}{8}(x + 2) \tag{3}$

or

$y = \dfrac{1}{8} x + 7\frac{1}{4}. \tag{4}$

Now, any takers on my bet?

Hope this helps.  Good Solstice Season to All,

and as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: +1, Didn't see the trig explanation for the perpendicular line's slope before.

Comment: Thanks!  How else do you do it?  I guess similar triangles or some such.  Seasonal Joys!